# Properties in my application.properties file are greyed out, i get Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Hi all, I get the below error when i run my application in intelij trying to connect to mysql

```java
2019-09-27 13:26:52.644  WARN 1084 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-09-27 13:26:52.648  INFO 1084 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-27 13:26:52.671  INFO 1084 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-27 13:26:52.674 ERROR 1084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have added the following to my application.properties file in the resources folder

```java
server.port = 8080
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false;

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/invoice
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

when i look at my application.properties file i notice that my properties are unused.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7ol.png)

this is my pom.xml file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.jade</groupId>
  <artifactId>invoicesystem</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- 1 To convert to springboot application the 1st thing to add is the parent below-->
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <name>invoicesystem</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>




  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!--2 To convert to springboot application the 2nd thing to do, add dependency: spring-boot-starter-web-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why is the pom targeting java 1.7?  [Spring requires](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html#getting-started-system-requirements) at least java 1.8.  Also, the latest release version is 2.1.8.

Comment: Thanks i have changed the target to 1.8 still no luck

Comment: '  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>'

Comment: First don't mix jars from different versions (mixing 2.1.4 and 2.1.5 spirng boot jars). Mysql doesn't need a version (spring boot manages it for you) and secondly, Spirng Boot already handles the plugin versions (no need to do that yourself again, which might even interfere). You aren't using the Spring Boot plugin to generate a proper Spring Boot jar. Finally Spring Boot 2.x requires java 1.8 as a minimum version, so 1.7 will eventually fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so after much deliberation, i decided to have a look at my resource folder, and the application.properties file and turns out that the resources directory was not marked as resources root, by right-clicking on the **resource folder directory**, hover over **Mark Directory as** and select **Resources Root** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvI7v.png)

Sorry for wasting everyones time, and thanks for all the help as i did use some of the configs mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dependency issue
Try to specify version for driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks i have added the the version, still no luck

Comment: Could you try: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` ?

Comment: I have changed the **spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ** in application.properties to read **spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** still no luck

Comment: Can you find `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` in Intellij Idea (ctrl+N) ?

Comment: I see both driver classes

Comment: You may try to connect with him through Teamviewer. It may help you find the real issue. @i.bondarenko

Answer (score 0):

Hi set on your property file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/invoice
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

On your pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>yourpackage.YourInitialApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[my github](https://github.com/PalituxD/message-delivery-microservice/tree/message-delivery-application/message-delivery-application)

Comment: Thanks Pablo, i updated the pom and properties as said and still getting the same application failed to start